# concatenat data tables coums

Tags: jquery, datatables, concatenation

i try to create table through jquery now i successfully display table and data

```
if (re.length > 0) {
    $("#services_schdulue").append
    $('#services_schdulue thead').append(
        "<tr><th>Conactenate</th><th>frequency</th><th>FDuration</th><th>FMileage</th><th>Lperformed</th><th>Nddatetime</th><th>Ndmileage</th><th>Rfrequ</th><th>Rduration</th><th>RMileage</th></tr>"
    );

    for (var i = 0; i < re.length; i++) {
        if (re[i] !== null) {
            $('#services_schdulue tbody').append(
                '<tr><td>' + con  +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][0] +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][1] +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][2] +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][3] +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][4] +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][5] +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][6] +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][7] +
                '</td><td>' + re[i][8] +
                '</td><</tr>');
        }
    }
}

var myTable = $('#services_schdulue').DataTable();
```

I try to to concatenate like this

```
var con = re[i][0].concat(re[i][1], re[i][2]);
```

but this show wrong result this show result like this:

[image]

First column should be 6 month(s) 1000.

How to do that?

Comment: you mean colspan ?

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: @MannanBahelim check updated

Comment: @campino2k check update please

Answer (score 0):

You need to use colspan property of the datatable:

For Demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/sgyzfw79/1/

Stack overflow :
[DataTables - Not working when added colspan for the last column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426972/datatables-not-working-when-added-colspan-for-the-last-column)

Datable official:

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Comment: with the reference of you fiddle i want like this please check image .. http://i.imgur.com/HVRjUlm.png